# Database repository (Oracle) vs File system as a repository for Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I want to use Pentaho for my work. After a bit of research I found that to store the ktr/kjb files I can have either database as a repository or I can use file system as a repository. However I don't find any benefits of using database as a repository over file system. The basic purpose of repository here is to create a common location where I can keep all the developed ktr/kjb files in production environment. Basically if I consider the database repository, it will hold all the developed ktr/kjb files in production and every time I need to run a job/transformation I will connect to database to get the respective ktr/kjb file (similar to how informatica stores transformation) on the other hand file based repository will be like a folder holding all the developed files.

Can somebody here will be able to explain pros and cons of both type of repository?

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When several people develop on the same jobs/transformations, the database repository will hold the changes, and ensure the latest versions.

The pros of a filesystem is of course ease of backup, no database connection that can trouble you, and the possibility to use other, more modern and mature version control systems for the files, than the database repositories use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the free community edition, I would definitely go with the file repository, along with external file-based version control and migration systems.  If you are using the enterprise edition, then you might want to consider the database repository, since you can then use Pentaho's built-in version control and migration systems.